# The right way to dispose Rx Disposable in presenter on orientation change

Tags: android, rx-java2, mvp, android-orientation, android-mvp

The problem: When I trying to rotate phone immediatelly after PullToRefresh, my Observable will not finish it's work because of dispose() method I calling in onPause. I understand why it's happening but I don't have any idea how to dispose without result loss.
If I dont call dispose, everything works great but I want to dispose my Disposable correctly to have no problems with memory leaks and etc.

My base presenter:

```
abstract class BasePresenter<T> {

    private var view: WeakReference<T>? = null

    /**
     * View reference
     * */
    fun getView(): T? = if (view != null) view!!.get() else null

    /**
     * We should call it in onResume() method in fragment
     * */
    fun bindView(view: T?) {
        if (view != null) {
            this.view = WeakReference(view)
            updateView()
        }
    }

    /**
     * We should call it in onPause() method in fragment
     * */
    fun unbindView() {
        view = null
        dispose()
    }

    protected abstract fun updateView()

    protected abstract fun dispose()
}
```

My base use case:

```
abstract class UseCase<TResult, in TParam> {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of [Observable] for specified params
     * @param params Params to create [Observable]
     */
    abstract fun createObservable(params: TParam?): Observable<TResult>

    /**
     * [Observable] which executes UseCase logic for specified params
     * @param params Params to create [Observable]
     */
    fun observable(params: TParam?): Observable<TResult> =
        createObservable(params).doOnError { }

    /**
     * [Observable] with null params
     */
    fun observable() = observable(null)
}
```

In View:

```
...

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    presenter.bindView(this@MainFragment)
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    presenter.unbindView()
}
...
```

This is Observable code in presenter (handling some network response):

```
fun update() {
    setRefreshing(true)

    getDataDisposable?.dispose()
    getDataDisposable = getDataUseCase
        .observable(param)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .switchIfEmpty {
            setRefreshing(false)
        }
        .subscribe { data ->
            [some manipulations with data]
            setRefreshing(false)
        }
}
```

If I don't call this, everything (of course) works as expected:

```
override fun dispose() {
    getDataDisposable?.dispose()
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/art-of-subscribe-unsubscribe-in-rxjava-12c30d315777

Comment: You must save your date in bundle, database or cache and read it after fragment recreation. You can also reload fresh data from the internet. If you want you can avoid calling "getDataDisposable?.dispose()" before "getDataDisposable = getDataUseCase..." with "switchMap{}".

Comment: https://medium.com/@czyrux/presenter-surviving-orientation-changes-with-loaders-6da6d86ffbbf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution. Now I dispose Disposable only on back button press and don't dispose it on view unbouned. So, I added method to base presenter:

```
...

/**
 * Method that should be called on back button click in fragment
 * It's planned that all [Disposable] objects will be disposed in implementation of this method
 * */
abstract fun onBackButtonClicked()

...
```

Presenter:

```
...

override fun onBackButtonClicked() {
    getChartDataDisposable?.dispose()
}

...
```

View (fragment):

```
...

override fun onBackButtonClicked() {
    presenter.onBackButtonClicked()
    navigator.back()
}

...
```

And some logic to intercept click on hardware back button:

Interface:

```
interface OnBackButtonClickListener {
    fun onBackButtonClicked()
}
```

Base fragment:

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment(), OnBackButtonClickListener {

    ...

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        (ctx as MainActivity).currentBackPressListener = this@BaseFragment
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        (ctx as MainActivity).currentBackPressListener = null
    }

    ...
}
```

Finally, overrided onBackPressed() method in activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    ...

    var currentBackPressListener: OnBackButtonClickListener? = null

    ...

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        currentBackPressListener?.onBackButtonClicked()
    }

    ...
}
```